# JSF ManagedProperty NullPointerException

Tags: jsf, managed-property

I have a `sessionScoped ManagedBean` in my JSF 2.2 project and i would like to invoke another `ManagedBean` as a `@ManagedProperty` This is my first `sessionScoped` bean:

```
public class MainWorkerMB implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @ManagedProperty("#{fragmentHandlerMB}")
    private FragmentHandlerMB fragmentHandlerMB;

    public FragmentHandlerMB getFragmentHandlerMB() {
        return fragmentHandlerMB;
    }

    public void setFragmentHandlerMB(FragmentHandlerMB fragmentHandlerMB) {
        this.fragmentHandlerMB = fragmentHandlerMB;
    }

    public void search() {

        fragmentHandlerMB.changeFrag("search_result.xhtml" , "Result Page" , -1);

    }
```

This is my another bean this is also `sessionScoped`:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class FragmentHandlerMB implements Serializable {

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.info("constructed..");
        // other code parts //

    }

    public FragmentHandlerMB() {
        super();
    }

public void changeFrag(String fragToOpen, String fragToOpenName, int pageIndex) {

//...

}
}
```

After that when i try to invoke my secound bean method i got `NullPointerException`:

```
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kebodev.managed.MainWorkerMB.search(MainWorkerMB.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

So it's looks like my bean doesn't exist.

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it, by removing the whole `<managed-bean>` configuration in `faces-config.xml` and add `@ManagedBean @SessionScoped`anotation to my both `ManagedBean.`